# How to Pass Image bytes to Velocity template

Tags: java, velocity

I have a requirement of passing the image bytes to velocity template(I have image bytes ready) by using this velocity template I need to print the image..

I want to access these image bytes in the velocity template..
How can I access these bytes in the velocity template?

Can any one please help me on this..

Thanks

Comment: What stops you from writing it out to an image file and refer to the image file in your template?

Answer (score 3):

This is year old now but incase some one still is having same problem, this is the solution which will work for you.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStreamForBarcode = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", outputStreamForBarcode);
       String imageText = com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.Base64.encode(outputStreamForBarcode.toByteArray());
```

In the velocity template, you may have to call it like:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,${generatedImageText}" alt="imagename"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ImageIO's write method to write to a ByteArrayOutputStream specifying the desired format and then get the byte array.

Ex:

```
    BufferedImage bimage = ImageIO.read(new File("image.jpg"));
    ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(bimage, "JPG", bOut);
    byte[] imageBytes = bOut.toByteArray();
```

[Link to Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write%28java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.OutputStream%29)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion ... I have the image bytes ready.. I want to access these bytes in the velocity template.. how can I access these bytes in my template